# Advanced filter can't express ISNULL?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

These two filters return zero results:

- `resource.labels:* AND resource.labels.namespace_name:*`
- `resource.labels:* AND NOT resource.labels.namespace_name:*`

While this one returns plenty:

- `resource.labels:*`

I have three questions about this:

1. What's going on here?
2. More importantly, how do I exclude a particular value of
   namespace_name while *not* excluding records that don't define
   namespace_name ?
3. Similarly, how do I write a filter for all records that *don't* define namespace_name?

Comment: Does `resource.labels.namespace_name:*` return anything? A hunch is that you can't negate the field-exists. This may (!) be a consequence of indexing properties that exist (and thus, records without the property, not appearing in the index). A solution (not available through the console) would be to grab the logs and then exclude those that match the value of `namespace_name` that you wish to exclude. Yes: 2 steps and you'd need another tool (perhaps jq).

Comment: You're correct; I've pre-filtered the set of results to exclude those that define namespace_name, in order to make my explanation of my problem simpler.

Comment: According to your theory, Stackdriver is just inherently incapable of representing my query? In that case, would exporting the logs to another system via "sinks" help me? I want to preserve stackdriver's capability to "`tail`" its logs in near-realtime though, so perhaps my set of constraints is unsatisfiable... for example, I can't find any way to tail stackdriver logs from the `gcloud` CLI.

Comment: It's common for customers to sink logs to e.g. BigQuery, Splunk both for richer querying and cost savings. But let's see whether others have a solution using Cloud Logging.

Comment: I was unclear. I like the query capabilities of bigquery, but I would want to be able to have a real-time view of the (filtered) results as they are created, like I do in stackdriver with the "play" button.

Comment: I've pinged a colleague to see whether they've a solution for you. Have you contacted your account team for help with this?

Comment: @DazWilkin: No. I don't know that I have such a thing.

Comment: Let me see whether I can track down your account team for you. Pleased to see my colleague has replied to your original question.

Comment: OK, I've found your account team and they'd like to connect with you (too). Please email me at @google.com -- my Google handle is the same as my Stack Overflow one -- and I'll fold you into a thread with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on Stackdriver Logging and have worked with the code that handles queries.

You are correct: something's up with the presence operator (`:*`), and it works differently than the other operators. As a result the behavior of a negated presence operator is not intuitive (or particularly useful).

We consider this a bug, and it's something that I'd really like to fix; however, fixing this class of bug is a lengthy process, so I've proposed some workarounds.

> 1. What's going on here?

I cannot reproduce your first "zero result" filter: `resource.labels:* AND resource.labels.namespace_name:*`

This gives me a large list of logs that contain the `namespace_name` label. For what it's worth, `resource.labels.namespace_name:*` implies `resource.labels:*`, so really you only need the latter half of this filter.

Your second "zero result" filter: `resource.labels:* AND NOT resource.labels.namespace_name:*`

... runs into a bug where field presence check (`:*`) does not interact properly with negation.

> 2. More importantly, how do I exclude a particular value of namespace_name while not excluding records that don't define namespace_name ?

While not required by the logging API, GCP-emitted resources generally emit the [same sets of labels for a given resource type](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources). You can take advantage of this by using `resource.type` to isolate resources-with-label from resources-without-label, then only apply the label constraint to the resources-with-label clause:

```
(resource.type != "k8s_container") OR
(resource.type = "k8s_container" AND resource.labels.namespace_name != "my-value")
```

Here, we are relying on all `k8s_container`-type entries having the `namespace_name` label, which should generally be the case. You can modify this to select multiple Kubernetes-prefixed resources:

```
(NOT resource.type:"k8s_") OR
(resource.type:"k8s_" AND resource.labels.namespace_name != "my-value")
```

... or use a complex `resource.type` clause to specifically select which you want to include/exclude from the namespace matching.

```
(NOT (resource.type = "k8s_container" OR resource.type = "k8s_pod")) OR
((resource.type = "k8s_container" OR resource.type = "k8s_pod") AND resource.labels.namespace_name != "my-value")
```

You cannot query for a `k8s_container` type that does not have the `namespace_name` label, but those should generally not be emitted in the first place.

> 3. Similarly, how do I write a filter for all records that don't define namespace_name?

You can't do this right now because of the bug. I think your best bet is to identify all of the [resource types](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources) that use `namespace_name` and exclude those types with a `resource.type` filter:

```
NOT (
  resource.type = "k8s_container" OR
  resource.type = "k8s_pod" OR
  resource.type = "knative_revision")
```

Note that, as mentioned earlier, while it's *possible* (allowed by the API) to have a `k8s_container` resource without a `namespace_name` label, emitted `k8s_container` logs should generally have the label.

Comment: Thanks! Would sinking everything to bigquery or another query engine help, here?